# How do I retrieve results from mysql where a timestamp is between 11pm yesterday and 11pm today?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a simple mysql table called messages with the following fields:

- ID(int)
- MESSAGE(varchar)
- CREATE_DATE(timestamp)

I simply want to make a query that returns all records where CREATE_DATE is between 11pm yesterday and 11pm today.

When saying yesterday and today I mean by getting the current date from mysql, not hardcoding it in.

Comment: Reference: [11.7. Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking at them. For some reason I am just not connecting the dots right now and thought someone here could probably do it in no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where create_date 
between concat_ws(' ',curdate(),'23:00:00') - interval 1 day 
and
concat_ws(' ',curdate(),'23:00:00')
```